# How to retrieve correlation matrix from glm models in R

Tags: r, glm, variance

I am using the gls function from the nlme package. You can copy and paste the following code to reproduce my analysis.

```
library(nlme)  # Needed for gls function

# Read in wide format
tlc = read.table("http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/fitzmaur/ala2e/tlc.dat",header=FALSE)
names(tlc) = c("id","trt","y0","y1","y4","y6")
tlc$trt = factor(tlc$trt, levels=c("P","A"), labels=c("Placebo","Succimer"))

# Convert to long format
tlc.long = reshape(tlc, idvar="id", varying=c("y0","y1","y4","y6"), v.names="y", timevar="time", direction="long")

# Create week numerical variable
tlc.long$week = tlc.long$time-1
tlc.long$week[tlc.long$week==2] = 4
tlc.long$week[tlc.long$week==3] = 6

tlc.long$week.f = factor(tlc.long$week, levels=c(0,1,4,6))
```

The real analysis starts from here:

```
# Including group main effect assuming unstructured covariance:
mod1 = gls(y ~ trt*week.f, corr=corSymm(, form= ~ time | id), 
       weights = varIdent(form = ~1 | time), method = "REML", data=tlc.long)
summary(mod1)
```

In the summary(mod1), the following parts of the results are of interest to me that I would love to retrieve.

```
Correlation Structure: General
 Formula: ~time | id 
 Parameter estimate(s):
 Correlation: 
  1     2     3    
2 0.571            
3 0.570 0.775      
4 0.577 0.582 0.581
Variance function:
 Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
 Formula: ~1 | time 
 Parameter estimates:
       1        2        3        4 
1.000000 1.325880 1.370442 1.524813
```

The closest I can get is to use the following method.

```
temp = mod1$modelStruct$varStruct
Variance function structure of class varIdent representing
       1        2        3        4 
1.000000 1.325880 1.370442 1.524813
```

However, whatever you stored with temp, I cannot get the five numbers out. I tried as.numeric(temp) and unclass(temp), but none of them works. There is no way I can just get the five numbers as a clean numeric vector.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: You actually cannot use any data set to fit this model.  Can you please post a few lines of `chol.long`.  I also don't understand why your title asks for the correlation matrix, but the actual inquiry does not. `summary(mod1)$corBeta` gets the model correlation matrix.

Comment: summary(mod1)$corBeta gives the correlation matrix for the coefficients, the square root of which gives the s.e. for inference. I am asking for the correlation matrix for the error matrix. In this model, the it's unstructured variance-covariance matrix; so glm will estimates all of them. In an OLS regression, however, this is only a common variance (i.e. homoscedasticity) and all covariance between errors are 0.

Comment: Ha, I think Richard mixed up correlation matrix of the coefficients and the correction matrix of the errors.

Comment: I have just updated my example, so now it's reproducible.

Comment: I have answered your question below, is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `mod1$modelStruct$varStruct` in R console, R first inspects the class of it

```
> class(mod1$modelStruct$varStruct)
[1] "varIdent" "varFunc"
```

and then dispatch the corresponding `print` function. In this case, it is `nlme:::print.varFunc`. i.e., the actual command running is `nlme:::print.varFunc(mod1$modelStruct$varStruct)`.

If you run `nlme:::print.varFunc`, you can see the function body of it

```
function (x, ...) 
{
    if (length(aux <- coef(x, uncons = FALSE, allCoef = TRUE)) > 
        0) {
        cat("Variance function structure of class", class(x)[1], 
            "representing\n")
        print(aux, ...)
    }
    else {
        cat("Variance function structure of class", class(x)[1], 
            "with no parameters, or uninitialized\n")
    }
    invisible(x)
}
<bytecode: 0x7ff4bf688df0>
<environment: namespace:nlme>
```

What it does is evaluating the `coef` and print it, and the unevaluated `x` is returned invisibly.

Therefore, in order to get the cor/var, you need

```
coef(mod1$modelStruct$corStruct, uncons = FALSE, allCoef = TRUE)
coef(mod1$modelStruct$varStruct, uncons = FALSE, allCoef = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I need. I am really new to R. Could you please explain a little about your answer. It gives the right results, but I have no idea what you were saying and what are those "uncons = False" and "allCoef=True" supposed to mean? Thanks a million.

Comment: I have added a more detailed explanation. You can do `?coef.varFunc` to see the meanings of `uncons` and `allCoef`.